# Easily access merged commits through git show?

Tags: git

Given the following recent history, is there any way through something similar to `git show HEAD^` to access any of the commits that were merged in with the merge commit in HEAD?

```
*   abcdef1 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)  Merge pull request #242 from features/blah-blah-blah
|\
| * beeg00d (origin/features/api-v3, features/api-v3) ✨ upgrade app to API v3
| * c0ffee1  add feature flags
| * e3ca62a  update whoosiwhatsit gem to version 3.0
|/
*   fedcba1  Merge pull request #241 from features/yada-yada-yada
```

In other words, `git show HEAD` will show info for the `abcdef1` commit, and `git show HEAD^` will show it for fedcba1, but I want to see `beeg00d` and `c0ffee1` without having to type in the hash character by character (or *worse yet* using my mouse to copy and paste).  Is there any way, through a convenient shorthand similiar to `HEAD^`, to access those commits?

I don't want to see the *merge* commits, I want to see the *merge**d*** commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `HEAD^` means `HEAD^1` which means the *first* parent of `abcdef1` which is `fedcbca1`, while `HEAD^2` means the *second* parent of `abcdef1` which is `beeg00d`.  From that second parent, another `^1` leads to `c0ffee1` and a third `^1` leads to `e3ca62a`.  (A fourth leads back to `fedcba1`.)

Hence:

```
HEAD^2^1^1
```

selects `e3ca62a` for instance.

Any time you have `^1`, you can drop the `1`, giving:

```
HEAD^2^^
```

Any time you repeat *n* `^` characters in sequence, you can replace that with `~n`, giving:

```
HEAD^2~2
```

although in this case that's no shorter than just typing `^` twice.